# PHPExcel error function getNamespaces() on a non-object

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to parse excel files with help of PHPExcel library, here is my function for parsing tables

```
function readXLS($inputFileName) {
  require_once(LIB_PATH.'PHPExcel.php');

  $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);  
  $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);  
  $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

  $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
  $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
  $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
  $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
  $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);

  $arr_data = array();
  for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {  
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {  
      $value=$objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();  
      $arr_data[$row-1][$col]=$value;
    }  
  }
  return $arr_data;
}
```

When i am parsing `*.xlsx` format all works good, but when i uploading for parsing `*.xls` format i have an error `Call to a member function getNamespaces() on a non-object in <b>Z:\home\mysyte\www\trunk\UI\lib\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2003XML.php`

Comment: First point to note is that PHPExcel is identifying your .xls file as an Excel 2003 (SpreadsheetML) XML file, not as a BIFF format .xls file; but please provide the full error message (including the error line information in the Excel2003XML reader and any stack trace information... believe it or not, knowing where in a file an error occurs can help narrow down any debugging to try and identify the cause of your problem.

Comment: Reporting this on the PHPExcel discussion or issues board, together with an upload of your file might help, because it's clearly not what it claims to be. To get this message, it must have passed a basic check that identifies it as xml, so it has been loaded using simplexml_load_file... but this is clearly failing as the result is not an object

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getNamespaces() on a non-object in <b>Z:\home\site\www\trunk\UI\lib\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2003XML.php</b> on line <b>438</b><br />